# SQL Server 2008: CASE statement in WHERE Clause and short circuit query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I am trying to make this query in a procedure work.

Right now it filters out the data that is older than the retention period for statuses 6 and 8. There are other status too. I want to make sure that the retention logic is applied only for status in (6,8) and not for other type of statuses. This procedure doesn't return the data for other status. Can I short circuit the query to run only for 6 and 8 status and return the data for status other than 6 and 8?

```
DECLARE @ReportRetentionPeriod INT = 0
SELECT @ReportRetentionPeriod = [PropertyValue] FROM [CQM].[dbo].[CompanyProperties] WHERE [PropertyName] = 'ReportRetentionPeriod'

SELECT
    DISTINCT
    JD.[Id] AS JobDetailId
    ,JD.[EntityId]
    ,JD.[QueueStatusId] AS QueueStatus
    ,RF.[FileName]
    ,RF.[CreatedOn] AS GeneratedOn  
    ,QS.[Name] AS QueueStatusName
FROM [dbo].[JobDetail] JD
INNER JOIN [dbo].[QueueStatus] AS QS ON QS.[Id] = JD.[QueueStatusId]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ReportFile] RF ON RF.[Id] = JD.[FileId]
WHERE JD.JobId = 1234
-- Added codition to use file createdon for completed jobs and job detail createdon for error'd jobs
AND ((GETDATE() - @ReportRetentionPeriod) < CASE QS.[Id]
    WHEN 6 THEN 
        CONVERT(DATETIME, RF.[CREATEDON], 101)
    WHEN 8 THEN
        CONVERT(DATETIME, JD.[CreatedOn], 101)
    END)
```

The case statement is used since I have to use different dates for comparison for different status.

Comment: Well you could add an `ELSE` that has some constant date that will be guaranteed to be greater than `GETDATE() - @ReportRetentionPeriod`. Couple of things: (1) why are you running a convert? Are the dates not stored as dates? (2) please don't use shorthand like `GETDATE() - some_number` - this breaks with some date/time types. Please read [this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations).

Comment: Also, just a nitpick on nomenclature, since semantics are important: [`CASE` is an expression, not a statement](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression).

Comment: Maybe there is something you can do with RF.Id being present? Are you trying to say do this when both JD and RF exists vs. only JD exists?

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand. Yes, it should be CASE expression. And, I can't use a constant date in else. Yeah, I don't think I need CONVERT since those columns are already datetime.

Comment: @lrb, actually for status 8 (error) there won't be any RF data entry. The table will return null. That's why I am using JD which will always have data.

Comment: What does "can't" mean? If you want the comparison to always return true for Ids NOT IN (6,8) then you can say `ELSE '9999-12-31'`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, You are absolutely right. I don't know what was I thinking. My bad. Thanks. It worked too :)

Comment: Although, I implemented this as per Aaron's solution. I am not sure how to accept his answer but Allan's solution worked for me too. So I am accepting it since he took some time to write an alternate solution. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost any time you use `case` in a `where` clause, you've gone down the wrong road. Additionally, you need to specifically state that if the `QS.[Id]` is not 6 or 8, then no additional criteria is needed. As written, when `QS.[Id]` is not 6 or 8, you code evaluates `(GETDATE() - @ReportRetentionPeriod) < NULL`. Your where clause should be:

```
WHERE JD.JobId = 1234
AND (( QS.[Id] = 6 and DATEADD(DAY, -1*ReportRetentionPeriod, GETDATE()) 
                       < CONVERT(DATETIME, RF.[CREATEDON], 101))
     OR (QS.[Id] = 8 and DATEADD(DAY, -1*ReportRetentionPeriod, GETDATE()) 
                         < CONVERT(DATETIME, JD.[CreatedOn], 101))
     OR QS.[Id] not in (6,8))
```

While this ends up being a little longer, the odds are pretty good that it will perform better, as the optimizer will have more options in interpreting the `and`/`or` construction than it would in interpreting the `case`.

---

If it were me, I'd probably also put the date logic in the line where you get the retention period, rather than when it is evaluated:

```
DECLARE @ReportRetentionDate DATETIME
SELECT @ReportRetentionDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1*[PropertyValue], GETDATE()) 
FROM [CQM].[dbo].[CompanyProperties] 
WHERE [PropertyName] = 'ReportRetentionPeriod'

SELECT
    DISTINCT
    JD.[Id] AS JobDetailId
    ,JD.[EntityId]
    ,JD.[QueueStatusId] AS QueueStatus
    ,RF.[FileName]
    ,RF.[CreatedOn] AS GeneratedOn  
    ,QS.[Name] AS QueueStatusName
FROM [dbo].[JobDetail] JD
INNER JOIN [dbo].[QueueStatus] AS QS ON QS.[Id] = JD.[QueueStatusId]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ReportFile] RF ON RF.[Id] = JD.[FileId]
WHERE JD.JobId = 1234
    AND (( QS.[Id] = 6 and @ReportRetentionDate < CONVERT(DATETIME, RF.[CREATEDON], 101))
         OR (QS.[Id] = 8 and @ReportRetentionDate < CONVERT(DATETIME, JD.[CreatedOn], 101))
         OR QS.[Id] not in (6,8))
```

Comment: your original code worked for me. The edit looks cleaner, I have to try?it now but do we still need CONVERT as CREATEDON is DATETIME already.

Comment: Probably not. I had no way of knowing what datatype `CREATEDON` was, so I left the `convert` because it was in the original code.